# Book about a girl who wakes up on her birthday and she's floating

Tags: story-identification, time-travel, magic

I remember it's a book about a girl who wakes up on her birthday and she's floating. During the party a guest I think falls off a cliff and she rescues them, showing she has powers, so her family sends her to a school for mages where she makes friends under strict rules. Next door is a school for boys.. I remember they end up going underground in find a maze where they hang out and do magic, she's becomes like the link needed and travel through portals back in time to when Hitler was taking over, and they change events.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. In roughly which year did you read this book, and when do you think it might've been published?

Comment: Probably not the one, but [*Beswitched*](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/7745639-beswitched) has a girl transported back in time by magic who has to defeat Hitler.